# C++ basic calculator -

Tags: c++, operators, calculator

I wanna develop a unique calculator. So, I playing with it but now I'm really confused about this function:

```
//Calculate two input expressions.
@prvni - First expression.
@druhe - Second expression.
@operace - Specifies mathematical operations - addition, multiplication etc.
    int vypocti(int prvni, int druhe, char operace){

      return (prvni+operace+druhe);
    }
```

So, I'm trying to use the "operace" parameter as mathematical function. (Like example below.)

```
  if(dpik == '+'){
    cout<<vypocti(prvni, druhe, '+');
}
```

Can You help me?

Comment: You cannot this way, c++ isn't a scripting language. You have to map it to call the right mathematical operaiton instead: `if(operace == '+') { return prvni + druhe; }`

Answer (score 0):

πάντα ῥεῖ's comment is very helpful:

> You cannot this way, c++ isn't a scripting language. You have to map it to call the right mathematical operaiton instead: `if(operace == '+') { return prvni + druhe; }`